# Posts to my blog Url gives my meta tag as a description on facebook

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

I have read this earlier question:
[META Description and Facebook](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12179020/meta-description-and-facebook)
and applied the directions stated therein because our problems are similar.
The message returned by the debugger is included in the png file attached herein:
I cannot upload images yet, so I am providing a link:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4Z774E5dZ-9RU1zX1A3RGdHRWc

how do i resolve the problem
thanks